# Mock only a subset of all calls to a method

Tags: python, mocking

I would like to mock only a sub set of calls to a method using the [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) module.  So,

```
fubar = Fubar()
fubar.myMethod = Mock()
funar.myMethod.return_value = [fubar.myMethod(), 'MyMOck', fubar.MyMethod]
```

would call the read method `myMethod` the first and third time but would call the mocked method on the second call.  The reason I want to do this is to check for a race condition: the middle call should return way earlier than the first one and thus cause some problems.  At least, I hope I can do it this way.

Is this possible?  If so, how?  If not, why not?

Comment: Why on _earth_ would you want to do that?! Either you're testing the method or you're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
fubar = Fubar()
myMethod = fubar.myMethod # note instance fubar, resulting in a bound method.
fubar.myMethod = lambda self, calls = [myMethod, (lambda: 'MyMock'), myMethod]: calls.pop()()
```

This assumes that `myMethod` takes no arguments. You can either pass arguments in the body of the lambda, or partially-apply `myMethod`, as necessary.

If you want to select programmatically the calls to mock, you could use a generator instead of a list, and `next` rather than `pop`:

```
fubar.myMethod = lambda self, calls = iter([myMethod, (lambda: 'MyMock'), myMethod]): next(calls)()
```